# How to group the results of a calculation

Tags: sql-server, grouping, calculation

I have two tables: **dbo.company_data** which contains different companies and their country of origin, and the second table **dbo.sellers_data** which has the units sold to each other by these companies.

[image: first table:]

[image: second table:]

What I need to obtain is:
a table consisting of three columns - `country, export, import`, which contain the sums of the values of the exported (sold to other countries) and imported (purchased from other countries) goods for every country. Each country should appear in this table.

Comment: FYI - On StackOverflow you're expected to do some research and have a go and then post a question when stuck. Its not a site where you get people to write your SQL for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to aggregate import and export units using two `joins` and aggregated function `sum`.

```
select
  country,
  coalesce(sum(se.units), 0) as export_qty,
  coalesce(sum(si.units), 0) as import_qty
from company_data c

left join seller_data se
on c.company_name = se.seller

left join seller_data si
on c.company_name = si.buyer

group by
  country
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
  
  SELECT cd.Country, SUM(exports.units) AS export, SUM(imports.units) AS import
  FROM dbo.company_data cd
  LEFT JOIN dbo.sellers_data exports
    ON cd.Country = exports.Seller
  LEFT JOIN dbo.sellers_data imports
    ON cd.Country = imports.buyer
  GROUP BY cd.Country
  ORDER BY cd.Country
```